# How to get data from JSON with Axios?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux, axios

I am trying to fetch server side data in JSON format in a table with Axios, but can't understand how to get every field like `id`, `companyInfo` etc.

**json :**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "companyInfo": 1,
    "receiptNum": 1,
    "receiptSeries": "АА",
    "customerName": "Mark",
    "customerSurname": "Smith",
    "customerMiddleName": "Jk",
    "customerPhone": "0845121",
    "services": [
      2,
      16
    ]
  }
]
```

**axios :**

```
 store.dispatch((dispatch) => {
dispatch({type: Actions.FETCH_DATA_START})
axios.get("http://localhost:3004/paymentReceipts")
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: Actions.RECEIVE_DATA, payload: response })
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch({type: Actions.FETCH_DATA_ERROR, payload: err})
  })
```

**reducer :**

```
export const initialState = {
  paymentReceipts: []
};

export default handleActions<FetchData>({
  [Actions.FETCH_DATA_START]: (state, action) => {
    return ;
  },
  [Actions.FETCH_DATA_ERROR]: (state, action) => {
    return;
  },
  [Actions.RECEIVE_DATA]: (state, action) => {
      console.log("DONE WITH STATE");
    return {...state, 
        paymentReceipts :  action.payload
    }
  }
}, initialState)
```

**App**

```
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export class App extends React.Component<App.Props, App.State> {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("CONTAINER IS ");
    console.log(this.props.receiveData);

    return (
      <div className={style.normal}>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: RootState) {
  return {
    receiveData: state.receiveData
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {

  };
}
```

This is what I get from `console.log`:

[image: This is what I get from <code>console.log</code>]

So how to get this values from JSON?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will get all your data into `response.data`.

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3004/paymentReceipts")
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: Actions.RECEIVE_DATA, payload: response.data }) //Change
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch({type: Actions.FETCH_DATA_ERROR, payload: err})
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, its fixed situation, but i still dont know how to get pair elements
like `id = 1, receiptSeries = АА` etc

Comment: just try to print `console.log(response.data)`

Answer (score 6):

To access a single attribute within your json-response you can simply do:

```
response.data.<attribute>
```

e.g.:

```
   axios.get("http://localhost:3004/paymentReceipts")
  .then((response) => {
    dispatch({ type: Actions.RECEIVE_DATA, payload: response.data, id: response.data.id }) //Change
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch({type: Actions.FETCH_DATA_ERROR, payload: err})
  })
```

Depending on the structure of your json and how it's formatted (e.g. array of objects) you have to iterate through it.

Comment: Is `data` a keyword from `axios` library?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios) there are several keywords you can call on `response`. For example: `response.data`, `response.status`, `response.headers` etc. I'm not confident enough to say that this works in every enviroment and setup, but yes, it is a "keyword" for an `axios response`

Answer (score 2):

If you've received text instead of JSON,just like I did,

With async/await, it's simply,

```
let results = await axios.get("http://localhost:3004/paymentReceipts")
try {
  let response = JSON.parse(results.request.response)  
  dispatch({ type: Actions.RECEIVE_DATA, payload: response })
} catch(err) {
  dispatch({type: Actions.FETCH_DATA_ERROR, payload: err})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import  Axios  from "axios";
import React ,{useState}from "react";
import { useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const FrtchData = () =>
{
    const navigate = useNavigate();
const [emp,setEmp]=useState([])
Axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
.then(res=>setEmp(res.data))

return (
    <div>

    {
        emp.map((emp,index) => <li key={index}>{emp.title}</li>)
    }
     <button onClick={()=>navigate("/home")}>Logout</button>
     
    </div>
)

}
export default FrtchData
```

Comment: What does this code do? What is impoved? Can you edit the post so that future comers know what this code means?

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import  Axios  from "axios";
import React ,{useState,useEffect}from "react";
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const FrtchData = () =>
{
    const navigate = useNavigate();
   
         const [users,setUsers] =useState([])
        useEffect (() =>{
            const asynfunc=async () =>{
                await Axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products')
                .then(res=>setUsers(res.data))
            }
            asynfunc()
        },[])
        
        return (<div>
            {
                users.map((users,index) => <li key={index}>{users.title} </li>)
            }
            <button onClick={()=>navigate("/home")}>Logout</button>
        </div>)

}
export default FrtchData
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).